# How to execute Java code from String?

Tags: java

I have many many fields in Super class that's why I want to use reflection in order to initialize sub object from super

in the sub class I have

```
public class Bot_PageTrack extends PageTrack {
    public Bot_PageTrack(PageTrack pt) {
        for (Field field : PageTrack.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            String code = "this." + field + " = " + "pt." + field;
            //HOW DO I EXECUTE THIS CODE??????????
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it that way? Wouldn't it be better to just initialize the fields in the `Bot_PageTrack` constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you said it: Use reflection:

```
class Bot_PageTrack extends PageTrack {
    public Bot_PageTrack(PageTrack pt) {
        for (Field field : PageTrack.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            // this.field = pt.field
            try {
                field.set(this, field.get(pt));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalAccessError(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this only makes sense for copying from *another* `PageTrack` object, not your own superclass, because you already have those available.